# Which is most suitable to begin programming (java vs c#) for an intermediate php programmer

Tags: c#, java, php

i am a php programmer who has no previous programming experience neither in java nor in c#(sharp). My goal is to learn both languages java and c#, so i am looking for an experienced programmer who has in depth knowledge of both languages to suggest me which one to start first in order to make my learning process easier and to help me grasp fast on the second language once i have finished learning the first. *(e.g some people find it easier when they learn the difficult language first or the one that has more features and programming aspects so once they are through and they start the second one they find the learning process like walking in the park)*

Comment: Should I learn French Canadian before I learn French as spoken in Ivory Coast ?

Comment: should be community wiki

Answer (score 14):

The languages are more alike than different so I doubt it matters much. Flip a coin.

Answer (score 1):

Java and C# aren't too different from each other, so it doesn't matter much. C# does have a few programming concepts that java does not have (anonymous functions, operator overloading and LINQ), which makes it a bit more interesting and (at least for me) fun to write. So I guess I would recommend to start with C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find someone who will help you with random questions and knows one of them well, go with it.

Otherwise, maybe play with Eclipse for a day, play with Visual Studio for a day, and stick with the one with the easier IDE for you to use.

They're pretty darn similar.

Comment: Visual Studio is definitely easier than Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin unless you are looking for a specific job or course and the choice might be a bit more important.

Java was my first OO language, then i studied it at uni, then I got my first job as a c# dev.

Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin that both languages are similar, however C# should have less resistance to learn because its IDE and tools are better integrated.

I know this is debatable but you could spend hours installing Apache, Eclipse, MySQL whatever just to make your first hello world servlet or jsp to work. Make sure the jars are there in the appropriate lib folder, download the appropriate jdbc driver, you know the drill.. this is frustrating..

With C#, just install the latest [visual studio express](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/) and it just work. No need to worry about database driver and all the non productive stuff, debugging also work out of the box. Debugging in Eclipse may not work straight away.., you may need to install certain plugin or configure it, this 'trivial' thingy can eat hours of your time that you could better spend learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

c# is easier to do form stuff which i think is good for learning on, but they much the same